# Error when including new column to uniqueness constraint in table for iOS coredata

Tags: ios, core-data, unique-constraint

```
0  CoreData                       0x19869d080 -[NSManagedObjectContext _thereIsNoSadnessLikeTheDeathOfOptimism].cold.1 + 28
1  CoreData                       0x1984eef0c -[NSManagedObjectContext _generateOptLockExceptionForConstraintFailure:] + 22
2  CoreData                       0x1983b97b4 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 1992
```

Running into this error for a small percentage of users after including a new column to a uniqueness constraint on a table in CoreData. The merge policy is set to `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy` for the context in which the object is being saved.

My expectation is that there should be no exception since a merge policy is specified. I am digging through CoreData documentation to try and make sense of this error message, but I cannot find any information for what `_generateOptLockExceptionForConstraintFailure` means.